# What storage (hdd if possible) is my lenovo ideacentre g5 14IMB05 capable of?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, compatibility

So yeah, the question is in the title, I don't know too much about computer upgrades... But I would like to upgrade my computers storage to 1tb or 2 tb hdd, for games primarily. The computer is a lenovo ideacentre g5 14IMB05 and I don't know if it is even possible to upgrade the storage internally since it's a compact desktop...

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/IdeaCentre/IdeaCentre_G5_14IMB05?M=90N90003UK

> Up to 2 drives, 1x 3.5" HDD + 1x M.2 SSD • 3.5" HDD up to 2TB • M.2
> SSD up to 1TB

Source Lenovo sheet to pick by region

https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/IdeaCentre/IdeaCentre_G5_14IMB05

So:  Yes you upgrade the disk capacity in this machine for both SSD and HDD.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo's support site says your machine can have:

- 3.5" HDD up to 2TB
- M.2 SSD up to 1TB

The manual with instructions should be [here](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/g5_14imb05_g5_14amr05_c5_14imb05_ug_en_202007.pdf?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide).